# Parsing Post Form Data Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, forms, parsing, express, middleware

I am getting form data in this form

```
'------WebKitFormBoundarysw7YYuBGKjAewMhe\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"a"\r\n\r\nb\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarysw7YYuBGKjAewMhe--\r\n
```

I'm trying to find a middleware that will allow me to access the form data like:

```
req.body.a // -> 'b'
```

I've tried

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

Is there a problem with my implementation or am I not using the correct middleware?

Comment: I think body parser stopped supporting form data parsing. Their github page has alternative form data parsers like busboy.

Comment: I am trying busboy and my onfield event is giving me a fieldname of "------WebKitFormBoundary10WDBTqcGz382i2e
↵Content-Disposition: form-data; name"

Comment: `bodyParser.urlencoded` is used to parse URL encoded form data. You should look into a `multipart/form-data` parser.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The tool that worked was [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty)

```
app.post('/endpoint', function (req, res) {
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        // fields fields fields
    });
})
```

Comment: but this tool is for multipart/data form i am just submiting text/plain form

Answer (score 10):

The library which worked for me was express-formidable. Clean, fast and supports multipart requests too.
Here is code from [their docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable)

Install with:

```
npm install -S express-formidable
```

Here is sample usage:

```
const express = require('express');
const formidable = require('express-formidable');

var app = express();

app.use(formidable());

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  req.fields; // contains non-file fields 
  req.files; // contains files 
});
```

Comment: It can also be used if you are using multer for any file upload/download logic. Such a great tool, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 9):

The above two answers are correct but now those methods are outdated. `multer` is a better method to access form data. Install it by the following command: `npm install multer`

some useful body parsers.

*Body-type: parser*

- form-data: multer
- x-www-form-urlencoded: express.urlencoded()
- raw: express.raw()
- json: express.json()
- text: express.text()

Comment: According to expressjs doc, Multer will not process any form which is not multipart (multipart/form-data).

Answer (score 1):

You can use multer package:

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const app = express();
const upload = multer();

app.post('/submit-form', upload.none(), (req, res) => {
  // Access form data here
  const formData = req.body;
  console.log(formData);
  
  // Handle the form data
  // ...
  
  res.send('Form submitted successfully');
});
```

The parsed form data is available in req.body.

Answer (score 0):

-better to use multer.

-But if you want to use bodyParser.urlencoded convert it into URLSearchParams data type

```
demonstration:-
 let fd=new FormData("id_of_form")
let sp=new URLSearchParams()
for(let [k,v]:fd.entries()) sp.append(k,v)
```

- make header 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded ' and pass sp to body.

-happy coding