# form-data is getting undefined in a Node/Express API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, httprequest, postman

I am trying to develop a simple API using NodeJS and Express. But Whenever I am trying to make post request using PostMan and form-data, in `req.body` I am getting `undefined`, though I have used,

> Accept: application/json
>
> Content-Type: application/json

in `Header` of my request.

[image]

But if I submit data using `raw` json format, I am getting `req.body` data and everything is working nicely.

[image]

In both cases, I am using `npm body-parser` and tried using following codes and in my project's app.js,

> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })) //tried both, true and false
> app.use(bodyParser.json())
>
> app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }))
>
> app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'text/xml' }));

I am not sure what is the problem, is the problem occuring from PostMan or there is problem in my code? Can anyone help e to explain the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: can u share express.js code

Comment: Form Data is something different,  it's not what you send Json with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing Post Form Data Node.js Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654747/parsing-post-form-data-node-js-express)