# Posting form data with fetch api

Tags: node.js, fetch-api, form-data

I'm trying to post formdata with help of fetch api. Code :

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("nickname", "johxns");
formData.append("password", "john_password");
formData.append("email", "john@server.com");


fetch("http://example/page", {
    body: formData,
    method: "post"
})
```

But in backend I'm recieving empty req body { }.
An object can be posted but why can't I post form data.
How to get this form data in backend.

Comment: then your problem is rather _parsing_ form data: [Parsing Post Form Data Node.js Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654747/parsing-post-form-data-node-js-express)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell that you are sending form data not just body.
Add

```
headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
```